# помогите составить запрос на создание сообщества Вконтакте

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, android-vksdk

Нужно составить запрос с помощью VK SDK Android, который будет отправлять название Сообщетва `title`, описание `description` и тип `type`.

Название и описание я беру из `EitText`, а тип по умолчанию `event`

```
name = editName.getText().toString();
    description = editTheme.getText().toString();
    type = "event";
```

Далее согласно [документации](https://vk.com/dev/android_sdk) я подготавливаю запрос

```
VKRequest createEvent = new VKRequest("groups.create", VKParameters.from(
                    "title", name,
                    "description", description,
                    "type", type));
```

И отправляю его

```
createEvent.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    super.onComplete(response);
                }
```

В итоге ничего не происходит и группа не создается, помогите понять что я делаю не так

Comment: Очевидно что там должны быть и другие методы, кроме `onComplete`, в любом случае нужно сначала увидеть что прилетело от сервера, а потом уже строить свои рассуждения.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev logcat выводит следующее `2019-05-27 13:05:39.500 4779-4779/com.takewithyou I/TakeWithYouError: com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest@8ddd44a{groups.create title= description= type=event }` получается, что мой editText не записывается в String name?